# have maven download a jar as a dependency

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, dependency-management

There is a website with a jar I want to use in my project.  I could download it, and make a local dependency on it, but that is lame.

Other people will build this project.  I don't want to clutter source control by checking it in.  I want to comunicate where the resource can be downloaded from and to easily change the versions.  At some point I would like to attach the sources and javadocs.

Is there a plugin that will let me use the URL and download it to my .m2 with a spoofed pom?

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it, is to search for the jars in Maven's central repo:

http://search.maven.org/

This gives you enough data to build the dependency in your pom.xml file

Example:

If I wanted to add jSoup to my project as dependency, then I go and search in the central repo

and add the dependency to the pom file with the info that's in there:

[http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.jsoup%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jsoup%22](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.jsoup%22%20AND%20a%3a%22jsoup%22)

```
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
         <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
         <version>1.7.3</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

I think maven2 repo is included by default when creating the super pom, so you don't have to write it, it will look there by default.

Comment: thanks, but I'm looking specifically for cases when the jar is not in the central (or any other) maven repo.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to set up a Nexus or Artifactory repo for the team available over the network. Download the jar from the third-party location, and then upload it with the proper pom GAV values to your new local repo. Then add the URL of this repo to the `repositories` section of the pom. Everyone will get it when they sync up with version control.

Answer (score 0):

maven-install-plugin can install files in local repo and generate poms, usage example:

mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc14 -Dversion=10.2.0.3.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=ojdbc6_g.jar -DgeneratePom=true